# Is JWT call necessary for each api call?

Tags: api, jwt

I need to integrate my website to a third party api "getBooks".This API requires JWT token.I use the "getJWT" api to get the token.My question is whether i need to call getJWT api before every call to getBooks api ? Is there a better way to code this problem?

Website description - It does not have a login feature. Customers can browse books and buy any book without login.JWT is only required by third party for their api.

Comment: Don't know that API, but usually, a JWT has an expiration time, and as long as the token is not expired, you can use it for your calls. Only when you get a 401 response, you'll have to get a new token.

Comment: @jps The expiry time is 1 hour. My website uses multithreading. So should i use Singleton pattern for calling JWT and storing the token for 1 hour OR should i just call JWT for every request ? I was confused whether using Singleton will affect the performance.